# Extremal serial dependence

Tags: econometrics, autocorrelation, independence, extreme-value, extremal-dependence

As part of my analysis of heavy-tailed time series of company returns, I would like to check whether extreme returns exhibit serial dependence, i.e. if extreme events are followed by extreme events.

For now, I am only interested in testing uni-variate time series, i.e. I just want to check if an extreme return of company A has an impact on the returns of company A in the following days.

Since the autocorrelation function (ACF) of a time is looking at the whole return series (not only the extremes), it has limited value in assessing dependence dependence between extreme events.

In my search so far, I have found recent papers about the "extremogram" (http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1821  and http://www.uis.no/getfile.php/Konferanser/paper_RichardDavis.pdf), something they view as the extreme-value analog of the ACF of a stationary process.

They also write that the extremogram is similar to the tail dependence coefficient of a uni-variate time series. While looking for more information about the tail dependence coefficient, I think tail dependence coefficients are mostly used in the analysis of co-movements in the tails of two distributions - which I am not interested in (for now).

Now finally my question:

1. Are there any other methods available for estimating extremal serial dependence?
2. Are there any implementations of the extremogram available in R/MATLAB? (Note: I have also contacted the authors and asked if they can share their code with me.)
3. If there is no implementation available for the extremogram, are there any other applications available? (e.g. how could I calculate the tail dependence coefficient of a univariate time series in R/MATLAB).

Edit: Author of the extremogram papers replid to me and told me there is no "official" implementation of the extremogram in R/MATLAB yet, but he assured me that it is easy to implement. Will be working on my own implementation for the extremogram then.

Comment: There is now an extremogram package in R https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extremogram/extremogram.pdf

Comment: @user91283 If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it, since it answers part 2 / 3 of the question.

Comment: Olorun were you able to create your own Extremogram function? If yes can you help me?